# How can I tell if a Javascript object is a File?

Tags: javascript, file, prototype

I have a function that manipulates an object that contains an "upload" member that is of type File. I would like to detect that fact so that I can ignore it and skip over all objects of this type.

I tried a bunch of things in the console, but nothing seems to return "true".  Here's a transcript of my futile attempts from inside a console breakpoint:

```
> values.avatar
{upload: File}
> values.avatar.upload
File {name: "29_Drawing Hands by Escher.jpg", lastModified: 1446580115000, lastModifiedDate: Tue Nov 03 2015 14:48:35 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 1314300, …}
> values.avatar.upload.isPrototypeOf(File)
false
> File
ƒ File() { [native code] }
> File.prototype
File {constructor: ƒ, …}
values.avatar.upload.isPrototypeOf(File.prototype)
false
> values.avatar.upload.prototype 
undefined
> File.isPrototypeOf
ƒ isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }
> File
ƒ File() { [native code] }
> values.avatar
{upload: File}
> File
ƒ File() { [native code] }
> File.__proto__
ƒ Blob() { [native code] }
> values.avatar.upload.__proto__
File {constructor: ƒ, …}
values.avatar.upload.isPrototypeOf(File.__proto__)
false
> values.avatar.upload.isPrototypeOf(Blob.__proto__)
false
```

Clearly I lack a fundamental understanding of how native types and prototypes work in Javascript.

Comment: Try `values.avatar.upload instanceof File`

Answer (score 11):

You can check it using [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) keyword.

```
if (values.avatar.upload instanceof File)
  // yes, it's a File type.
else
  // no, it's not.
```

Answer (score 4):

check

```
values.avatar.upload instanceof File
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also test by it's prototype:

```
if(values.avatar.upload.prototype === File.prototype) {
  // true
} else {
 // false
}
```

For instance, you may use:

```
File.prototype.isPrototypeOf(values.avatar.upload)
```

For eg. the following will return true:

```js
var file = new File([""], 'text.txt');
console.log(File.prototype.isPrototypeOf(file));
```

Comment: instances don't have a `prototype` property. This is just completely wrong.

Comment: I can't see OP has instance.

Comment: Second snippet is not functionally equivalent to first snippet, but the more canonical answer is `values.avatar.upload instanceof File`

Comment: second is for instance as you commented.

Comment: `...but the more canonical answer is ` - I have tried to stick with OP.

Comment: Let me make it as clear as possible for you. `File.prototype.isPrototypeOf(values.avatar.upload)` is correct. It is equivalent to `values.avatar.upload instanceof File`, which is much easier to understand. `values.avatar.upload.prototype === File.prototype` is _wrong_. There's no point even leaving that in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clear with your statement. Both are placed in my answer for different use case. First one is for simply object and another is for instance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189355/discussion-between-bhojendra-rauniyar-and-patrick-roberts).